# How to solve a zero sum game

Tags: matrices, game-theory

So i have this question:

[image]

I see the matrix is reduced by dominant strategies.

However I do not understand the 'elimination by dominant strategies' that the answer sheet imposes.

It says that the third column is dominated by the second column. But  shouldn't the second column be dominated by the third, the reason for which the third column disappears?

Then , with the remaining matrix, the second row is dominated by the third row. Then shouldn't the third row by eliminated ?

What am i missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The payoffs in the matrix are all from the row player's point of view.  The column player always likes column 2 better than column 3 (since entry-by-entry the column 2 values are better for the column player than the column 3 values).  So the column player would never play column 3.

Comment: Does this mean that in a zero sum game the payoffs are ALWAYS from the row player's point of view?

Comment: I dont really undertand it. 'the column player always likes column 2 better than column 3' but how?  2 is greater than 0, 3 is greater than 2 , and 2 is greater than one.

Comment: The convention is that the values in the payout matrix show a payment from the column player to the row player.

Comment: At this point im kind of lost. sorry....

Comment: do you mind expanding your argument a bit more ?

Comment: For example: If the row player picks row 2 and the column player picks column 3, the value seen in  the matrix is 3.  This means that the column player pays 3 units (dollars or whatever) to the row player.  This means that greater numbers are relatively better for the row player, while lesser numbers are relatively better for the column player.

Comment: Because i see it that the third column has higher values than the second column , so we eliminate it?

Comment: @SaraSaletti Consider the numbers to mean the amount of money the column player must pay the row player. The column player wants to minimize this number; the row player wants to maximize it.

Comment: Understood! Thanks!